# If $f+g+h-m \leq c$ then $f+g+h \leq d$ for some $d \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f, g, h, m : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ differentiable functions. Suppose that, there exists a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ ($c>0$) such that
$$f(t)+g(t)+h(t)-m(t) \leq c, \; \forall \; t \in \mathbb{R}.$$

**Question.** There exists a constant $d \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that
$$f(t)+g(t)+h(t) \leq d, \; \forall \; t \in \mathbb{R}.$$

It is possible to guarantee the existence of such a constant $ d $?

Intuitively, it seems to be true and moreover $d\geq c$, but I couldn't prove it. Any answers, tips or suggestions?

Comment: Suppose $f(t) + g(t) + h(t) = m(t)$. If $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} m(t)= \infty$, why is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick basically any standard function like $t,\, t^2, \,\sqrt{\vert t\vert},\, \log(1+|t|),\, \exp(t) $ or $\, t\sin(t)$. Then, define $f(t)$ exactly as the one you picked. Then, define $m(t)=f(t)$ and $g(t)=h(t)=0$. Hence, $$
f+g+h-m=0 \quad \hbox{but}\quad f+g+h=f=\hbox{unbounded}.
$$